# Setting a state variable in an effect based on comparing the value of another state variable

Tags: react.js

I've gone through the docs in a fair bit of detail and understand that a setState function can be passed a function if the previous state is needed.

Here I am trying to, based on the state of a variable, set the state of another variable. This seems logically correct to me, but just feel weird. Looking for someone to sanity check it.

```
export default function Comp(props) {
  const [command, setCommand] = useState("");
  const [items, setItems] = useState(allowedTags);
    
  useEffect(() => {
    setCommand((prevCommand) => {
      if (command !== prevCommand) {
        const items = syncFunc(allowedTags, command);
        setItems(items);
      }
      return command
    });
  });
}
```

I also understand that this effect will run after every render. But will the effect cause itself to be scheduled to run again since it is updating state?

Comment: Did you test it? Does it produce the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use effect requires a second parameter, the list of dependencies for the effect.

This effect declares that you want to re-compute the items state when command is updated.

```
useEffect(() => {
        const items = syncFunc(allowedTags, command);
        setItems(items);
  }, [command]);
```

All the code you have to check if the dependency had updated is actually the sole purpose of the `useEffect` function. Simply give it some dependencies and it will check every render if those dependencies have been updated.